# Why is my Outlook add-in not running in main thread?

Tags: multithreading, outlook, add-in

I'm having the problem that my Outlook add-in is not running in the processes main thread. This applies at least to some callbacks, maybe more, I'm still investigating. It's a big problem since several important API functions only work from the main thread.

This happens only at a customer's computer (Win8 + Outlook2013 64-Bit), but not on my computer with the same Windows/Outlook version.

I've never seen this before.

Any ideas what might trigger this?
Any hidden setting in Office, any third-party security tools?
Any build settings that I can use to prevent it?

Comment: Update: Even the first initialization call doesn't come from the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook always runs COM add-ins on the main thread.
What exactly makes you think that you are running on a secondary thread? How exactly does the problem manifest itself?

Comment: I'm using "Solution 1" from [this page](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/78801/How-to-get-the-main-thread-ID-of-a-process-known-b) to get the process' main thread id and compare it with GetCurrentThreadId(). On my computers they're identical. On the customer's computer they're different.

Comment: So Outlook can start other threads prior to starting its main UI thread. Again, why is it important? What is it exactly that you are trying to solve?

Comment: Many GUI functions only work from the main thread. My DLL isn't run in the main thread, so they don't work, causing lots of problems. AfxGetMainWnd() is just one example.